# What does this do: roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name and the documentation implies somehow that it would launch a turtlebot3 "remotely" i.e. when running this  launch file on another computer (not the robot itself.)  But I just cant understand how that can be and reading the .launch file didn't help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299064/what-does-this-do:-roslaunch-turtlebot3_bringup-turtlebot3_remote.launch/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

turtlebot3_remote.launch file includes robot_model and launch robot_state_publisher node.

```
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg multi_robot_name)"/>
  </node>
```

So, this makes to show state of your robot by tf. If you want more detail information, please visit below links.

- http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher
- http://wiki.ros.org/robot_model

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1